# Measurable Transformation: the converse of the definition

Tags: measure-theory, transformation

Given measurable spaces $(\Omega_1, \mathcal{F}_1)$ and $(\Omega_2, \mathcal{F}_2)$, and the mapping $T: \Omega_1 \rightarrow \Omega_2$, $T$ is said to be $\mathcal{F}_1/\mathcal{F}_2$ measurable if $T^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{F}_1$ for all $B \in \mathcal{F}_2$.

Can I claim that $T(A) \in \mathcal{F}_2$ for each $A \in \mathcal{F}_1$? If not, what is significant about the transformations which have/don't have this property?

Comment: For your first question, consider $\mathcal{F}_2 = \{ \emptyset , \Omega_2 \}$, with $\mathcal{F}_1$ being the power set of $\Omega_1$, where $\vert \Omega_1 \vert > 1$.

Comment: What is known: if $T$ is bijective, the spaces are nice (Polish spaces) and the sigma algebras are Borel sigma algebras then the conclusion is true. This, incidentally, is a very deep theorem, so don/t expect any simple useful theorem that gives the desired conclusion.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That sounds like a nice result. Do you have a reference for it so I can read about it?

Comment: Measure Theory by Cohn.

Comment: Thank you @KaviRamaMurthy. One more thing: the claim I stated is essentially saying that $T^{-1}$ is $\mathcal{F}_2/\mathcal{F}_1$ measurable. Now if both $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are measurable and $T$ is 1-1 onto, then $T: \Omega_1 \rightarrow \Omega_2$ is called a measurable isomorphism.